# Using bool as l-value

Tags: c++, iterator, int, boolean, dereference

This is compiling ok when **Type** is **int** but giving "error C2102: '&' requires l-value" when **Type** is **bool**. Why?

```
std::vector<Type> Vector;
Vector.push_back(false);
Vector.push_back(true);
Vector.push_back(true);

const void* Pointer = NULL;
for (std::vector<Type>::const_iterator it = Vector.begin(); it != Vector.end(); ++it)
    Pointer = &(*it);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector` is specialized for `bool`, and in that specialization, `*it` is not an lvalue.  It's not possible to point to individual `bool`s within the vector.

With the benefit of hindsight, this specialization is regarded as a mistake. Nowdays it is usually recommended to avoid using `vector<bool>`.  Alternatives include `std::bitset`.